# SDL2 - SDL_AudioSpec audio plays endlessly when not called in while loop

Tags: c++, audio, sdl-2

I've made this simple program according to [a github code](https://gist.github.com/armornick/3447121).
All you have to take care of is the while loop at the end of the main() method.

```
#include "SDL2\SDL.h"

constexpr const char* WAV_PATH = "applause.wav";

#include <iostream>
static Uint8* sg_pAudioPos;
static Uint32 sg_AudioLength;

struct CWavWrapper
{
    Uint32 m_Length;
    Uint8* m_pBuffer;
    SDL_AudioSpec m_Spec;
};
void ExitProgram(int code = 0)
{
    system("pause");
    exit(code);
}
void AudioCallback(void* pData, Uint8* pStream, int Length);
#undef main
int main()
{
    using std::cout; 
    using std::cerr;
    using std::endl;

    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_AUDIO) < 0)
    {
        cerr << "couldnt init audio: " << SDL_GetError() << endl;
        ExitProgram(1);
    }


    cout << "Loading wav... " << WAV_PATH << endl;
    static CWavWrapper Wav;
    if(SDL_LoadWAV(WAV_PATH,&Wav.m_Spec,&Wav.m_pBuffer,&Wav.m_Length) == NULL)
    {
        cerr << "couldnt load wav: " << SDL_GetError() << endl;
        ExitProgram(1);
    }
    Wav.m_Spec.callback = AudioCallback;
    Wav.m_Spec.userdata = NULL;

    sg_pAudioPos = Wav.m_pBuffer;
    sg_AudioLength = Wav.m_Length;

    cout << "Opening Audio..." << endl;
    if (SDL_OpenAudio(&Wav.m_Spec, NULL) < 0)
    {
        cerr << "couldn't open audio: " << SDL_GetError() << endl;
        ExitProgram(1);
    }
    cout << "Success! Starting Audio..." << endl;
    SDL_PauseAudio(0);
    while (sg_AudioLength > 0)
    {
        //If I remove this output line or as in the GitHub example not do the SDL_Delay() the wav gets played infinitely.
        //how does printing out a variable change its value (as it should do only in the callback)?
        cout << "sg_AudioLength: " << sg_AudioLength << endl;
    }

    SDL_CloseAudio();
    SDL_FreeWAV(Wav.m_pBuffer);

    ExitProgram(0);
}

void AudioCallback(void* pData, Uint8* pStream, int Length)
{
    if (sg_AudioLength == 0)
        return;
    if (Length > sg_AudioLength)
    {
        Length = sg_AudioLength;
    }

    SDL_MixAudio(pStream, sg_pAudioPos, Length, SDL_MIX_MAXVOLUME);

    sg_pAudioPos += Length;
    sg_AudioLength -= Length;
}
```

As you can see at the end of the main() function, I put a description on what happens when I remove the cout line.
I think it might has to do something with the AudioCallback only being called when a certain code is done. But I am not sure and I would like to get an answer to it.

EDIT: I've noticed that when anything gets processed in the while loop, the audio seems to play right. Does anything from compiling to run time notice that the loop does not change the variable and thinks that this is now an endless loop so the loop does not even try to check the variable again?

Comment: "how does printing out a variable change its value[?]" Usually via a bug elsewhere in the program. For example, without the time delay caused by the print statement, the infinite loop may starve whatever thread calls `AudioCallback` preventing the expected behaviour.

Comment: On your edit: Possible. Also consider [using `std::atomic`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic) to prevent other bits of shared variable nastiness.

Comment: I've added an extra paragraph at the end of my post. Regarding this, Does this occur because of a branch prediction or am I thinking wrong?

Comment: More likely the test being compiled out than a branch prediction fail.

Comment: atomic variables most likely do not play a role in this example as one writes and the other reads. I've added a cout into the AudioCallback() function and it shows that the variable sg_AudioLength is indeed changing thus the only thing being wrong is the while loop being pre processed, tricked into thinking it will always be true or false.